# How to avoid calculating rows caused by the join inside SUM()?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my database schema simplified:

```
// wallet
+----+--------+---------+
| id | credit | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | 1000   | 1       |
| 2  | 1500   | 2       |
+----+--------+---------+

// where_to_pay_ability
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | business_id | wallet_id |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 5           | 1         |
| 2  | 4           | 1         |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

And this is the current query I have:

```
select sum(credit)
from wallet w 
left join where_to_pay_ability wtpa on w.id = wtpa.wallet_id
where user_id = 1
```

It returs `2000`. Becuase there are two rows inside `where_to_pay_ability` table. That's a wrong credit for me. I want to `sum` rows once inside `wallet` table. So, **the expected result is `1000`.**

How can I do that?

---

It should be noted, I can do that `left join` with a sub-query that is `GROUP BY`ed `wallet_id` (Or `DISTINCT`). But, I need to have those `business_id`s.

So, I need a condition inside the `SUM()` to avoid calculating rows caused by the join.

Comment: Why not remove the `JOIN` after all, if you don't access any data from the other table?

Comment: Well @NicoHaase, As I said, it's a simplified version of what I want .. in reality, I need to select all columns from the `wallet` and `where_to_pay_ability` table.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to aggregate *before* joining:

```
select sum(credit)
from wallet w left join
     (select wtpa.wallet_id, count(*) as cnt
      from where_to_pay_ability wtpa
      group by wtpa.wallet_id
     ) wtpa
     on w.id = wtpa.wallet_id;
 where user_id = 1;
```

In your particular example, though, you could use `max()` because there is only one row.